# python pickle dump non ascii

Tags: python

I would like to write something to a file (a result obtained from GNUPG) using Python in Linux so that I can read it in later and see whether the signature and data are still valid.

When I try to write the result to file in the following way (lines 16-18 from my code):

```
with open(“result.txt”, “w”) as my_file:
    pickle.dump(signed_data, my_file)
my_file.close()
```

I get the following problem:

```
python eg1.py 
    File "eg1.py", line 16
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file eg1.py on line 16, but no encoding     declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Although I could change to problematic values to something else and change them back when I read them back in later, I am wondering if it will be possible for me to simply save the file as I intend do without changing it?

Comment: try opening the file in binary mode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message has no relation to the binary stuff (signed_data) you want to write, but with the python source file. You gave no indication, what line number 16 is, but the typographic apostrophes in the "open"-line could be the reason.

Comment: that was really well spotted. thank you so much. i can't believe what a silly thing it was causing that trouble!

Comment: I like to edit code and type shell commands in an mrxvt for this reason - it displays things that are gibberish to python or a shell, as gibberish.  Many shells today try to display things that make no sense to python or a shell, in a pretty way that confuses the tools.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Windows, then check into Unicode-related solutions, e.g. [linked here](http://mohsinpage.wordpress.com/2010/06/10/python-syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file/).